# MYSQL COUNT results and AVG them while grouping by a column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the average number of completions per day for the past 30 days and then average that. Here is an example of my Rundown table

```
RundownID | WorkOrderID | ForemanID | Completion | RundownDate
1         | 1           | 1         | 1          | 2017-10-27
2         | 2           | 1         | 1          | 2017-10-26
3         | 3           | 1         | 1          | 2017-10-20
4         | 4           | 1         | 1          | 2017-10-27
5         | 5           | 2         | 1          | 2017-10-27
6         | 6           | 2         | 1          | 2017-10-27
7         | 7           | 3         | 1          | 2017-10-25
8         | 8           | 2         | 0          | 2017-10-20
```

The results I am looking for is

```
ForemanID | ForemanAvg
1         | 4
2         | 2
3         | 1
```

It should take the total number of Completion rows in the last 30 days and average the total per day for each unique ForemanID. Then average the total per day to give me the average per last 30 days

I know I am close, but I just can't seem to get it configured right. Here is how far I got

```
SELECT
    ForemanID,
    COUNT(RundownDate) AS ForemanAvg
FROM Rundown
WHERE RundownDate > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '30' Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY ForemanID
```

RESULTS

```
ForemanID | ForemanAvg
23        | 70
24        | 100
25        | 100
26        | 76
27        | 109
29        | 11
```

EDIT:

I am getting closer. Using the following query I am getting the result I want, however it only gives me one ForemanID for some reason

```
SELECT 
    a.ForemanID,
    AVG(a.ForemanAvg)
FROM (SELECT
    RundownDate,
    ForemanID,
    COUNT(RundownDate) AS ForemanAvg
FROM Rundown
WHERE RundownDate > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '30' Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY ForemanID, RundownDate ) AS a
```

Comment: So what is wrong in the result you are getting?

Comment: They are not averaging 70, 100, a day. It should show more like 4-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query should work:

```
SELECT
    ForemanID,
    count(*)/COUNT(distinct RundownDate) AS ForemanAvg
FROM Rundown
WHERE RundownDate > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '30' Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY ForemanID;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: Always glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *"average the total per day for each unique ForemanID"*, then you need to add the date to the grouping:

```
SELECT
    ForemanID,
    COUNT(Completion) AS ForemanAvg
FROM Rundown
WHERE RundownDate > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '30' Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY ForemanID, RundownDate
```

Note: This is not called "average", this is a count. If you really want the average, then use `AVG(Completion)` instead of `COUNT(Completion)`.

**EDIT** To add an average row in addition to the daily total, you can do that in another query and use `UNION` to combine the two queries.

```
SELECT
    ForemanID,
    COUNT(Completion) AS ForemanAvg
FROM Rundown
WHERE RundownDate > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '30' Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY ForemanID, RundownDate 
UNION
SELECT
    ForemanID,
    AVG(Completion) AS ForemanAvg
FROM Rundown
WHERE RundownDate > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '30' Day))
AND Completion = 1
GROUP BY ForemanID
ORDER BY ForemanID
```

Comment: Exactly. I was getting confused too.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my question to be more clear. Your query is right I think but I need it to be averaged again. Just to clarify more, if foreman 1 completes 5, 6, 5, 3, 5, each day then the final row should show foreman 1 with an average of 4.8

Comment: And do you want to show the five rows (5, 6, 5, 3, 5) plus the average row (4.8), or only the average? See my updated answer.

Comment: What OP wants is : "(Total completion in last 30 days) / (No. of distinct dates on which completions happened in last 30 days)" ....See my answer.

Comment: @Harshil Yes, that's only obvious now after his last question update. +1 on your answer from me.